# How can I redirect to a mobile optimized page on a per-page basis in Concrete5?

Tags: concrete5

I have a web site that is fairly responsive and works on mobile devices and the desktop alike.

There’s just a couple of pages that are very complex and are impossible to make work both on desktops and mobile devices - e.g., they use background images with a specific portion that needs to be visible, or image galleries with desktop specific settings.

For those few pages, I’d like to be able to detect whether I’m on a mobile device, and render a different page instead.

I suppose I'll need to work on the core to do this. At which point of the C5 page rendering process would I ideally change away from the current page, and render a different one instead?

I can do something hacky by loading the other page in the template, rendering it, and then terminating, but that wouldn’t be very clean.

Is there a preferred, "Concrete5-y" process?

Answer (score 2):

Did you know you can set the visibility for different devices ? 
[image]

You can set it under the 'edit design' options for blocks, area's, stacks and I think even columns.

With this, you can hide or show parts of your page, depending on the screensize.

For the backgrounds, take a look here: http://www.concrete5.org/marketplace/addons/mrkdilkington-full-screen-background-image-and-overlay
You can set the focal point.

Comment: Aww crap, I should have mentioned I'm on 5.6 with this. Sorry. I'll take a peek at the plugin though, perhaps that (combined with media queries) solves the problem

Comment: If you are using a  bootstrap based theme, you can do the same by adding responsive classes to the blocks. See http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities.

Comment: Also I thought there was an option somewhere to set a mobile theme on 5.6...but I never used that myself.

Comment: There is an option for a mobile theme, but as far as I can see it is for the entire site only. I really need to switch the entire page (I know how to hide and show certain elements using media queries, but the backgrounds are acting up... perhaps your plugin helps, though)

Comment: That add-on is for 5.7, probably need a bit of rewriting. If you are ready to hack around a bit, here are some nice events you could hook into: http://legacy-documentation.concrete5.org/developers/system/events